# inject live data into POI spreadsheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, vaadin, spreadsheet

We are using Vaadin's Spreadsheet component in our web application.
Vaadin's Spreadsheet component uses Apache POI as the underlying engine.

Using the Apache POI library I've successfully extended the Vaadin Spreadsheet component to support a new formula type:

=njgetdata(source, element, filter)

The formula pulls data from our vaadin web application and allows calculations to be performed in the spreadsheet based on the returned data.

So far, so good.

The problem is that the value returned from njgetdata changes overtime (in some cases a few times a second).

Whenever the data changes I want to force the spreadsheet to re-calculate if there are any cells dependant on the changed data.

To make this efficient I'm guessing that I need to identify which cells are using the njgetdata formula and some how tell those cells to recalculate the formula to get the latest value.

I'm looking for recommendations on exactly how to do this and do it efficiently - e.g. I don't want the spreadsheet thrashing.

Comment: Apache POI will cache values for formula cells if you ask it to, and can invalidate the cache when a cell changes if you notify it. Maybe try that?

Comment: So how do you notify POI that a cell has changed? And what does that mean when its a formula?

Comment: See [the POI formula evaluation performance notes section in the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Performance)

Comment: So I'm confused how the formulaevaluator works. It appears that you create one by passing in the workbook, but I would have thought that every workbook would need its own evaluator to evaluate and calculate cells. If create my own how does the work book interact with it? If a user edits a cell does the workbook call evaulate on my formulaevaluator (that makes no sense). The second issue is ideally I just want to notify the cells that contain the formula. But I don't see a way of determining which cells are using my formula.

Comment: FormulaEvaluator knows which cells depend on which other ones. Tell it which ones you've changed, then when you ask it to recalculate it can skip ones which don't depend on the changed cells

Comment: So maybe I understand the source of my confusion. POI is simply an api for manipulating a spreadsheet. The vaadin addon builds a UI to display an excel spreadsheet managed by poi. I'm now thinking that this means that vaadin is calling the evaluate method on the POI when it needs to refresh a cell. It takes that value and displays it. So I'm thinking I need to get the formulaevaluator from the vaadin spreadsheet object. The flush the cache (or at least individual cells) when the formula changes. That would mean I only need to determine which cells contain my formula.

Comment: OK, so the Vaadin Spreadsheet object does have a formulaEvaluator: spreadsheet.getFormulaEvaluator(). I'm feeling very clever now ;) Now just to work out which cells contain a formula.

Comment: So found: spreadsheet.addCellValueChangeListener(listener); I'm guessing that if a user enters a formula I will get a listener event. I then check if my formua is used. I can then track the cells that contain my formula and if the value produced by the formula changes do a notify on each of the formula containing cells. But this still seems inefficient. Better ideas?

Comment: Normally you'd notify POI of the source cell changes, eg A1 was changed to contain 42 instead of 24, then you'd re-evaluate all your formulas and those which didn't depend on the changed cell would be skipped

Answer (score 1):

So after much ado and some great tips from Gagravarr I solved the             problem.

So here is a fully worked example.

Bascially I wanted to create a user defined function (UDF) for Vaadins Spreadsheet component which provided live updates to the UI.

Consider the case of a spreadsheet that wants to take live updates for a stock price, perform a calculation and dispaly the results. Each time the stock price changes the calculation should automatically update.

A live UDF lets you do just that.

So the example implements a UDF that allows you to write a spreadsheet formula of the form:
=getprice("IBM", "BID")

The getprice UDF will return the Bid price of IBM each time it changes.

So here are the three classes required.
Enjoy!

```
package au.com.noojee.dashboard;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import com.vaadin.addon.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Push;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Widgetset;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent     a browser
 * window (or tab) or some part of a html page where a Vaadin     application is
 * embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This     method is
 * intended to be overridden to add component to the user interface     and
 * initialize non-component functionality.
 */
@Theme("dashboard")
@Widgetset("au.com.noojee.dashboard.DashboardWidgetset")
@Push
public class SpreadsheetUI extends UI
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Spreadsheet spreadsheet;

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "SpreadsheetUIServlet",     asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = SpreadsheetUI.class,     productionMode = false)
    public static class SpreadsheetUIServlet extends VaadinServlet
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request)
    {

        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        this.setContent(layout);

        layout.setSizeFull();

        layout.addComponent(createSpreadsheet());
    }

    // Create the spread sheet and inject the UDF.
    Component createSpreadsheet()
    {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setSizeFull();
        spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        spreadsheet.setSizeFull();

        new DataSource().initFormula(spreadsheet);
        layout.addComponent(spreadsheet);

        return layout;
    }
}

package au.com.noojee.dashboard;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.AggregatingUDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.DefaultUDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.UDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;

import com.vaadin.addon.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

public class DataSource
{
    private static final String UDFNAME = "getstockprice";
    private Set<Cell> cellTracker = new HashSet<>();
    private GetStockPrice formula = new GetStockPrice();

    public void initFormula(Spreadsheet spreadsheet)
    {
        String[] functionNames =
        { UDFNAME };
        FreeRefFunction[] functionImpls =
        {  formula };

    // Get the UDF finder
    UDFFinder udfs = new DefaultUDFFinder(functionNames, functionImpls);
    UDFFinder udfToolpack = new AggregatingUDFFinder(udfs);

    spreadsheet.getWorkbook().addToolPack(udfToolpack);

    // We need to track what cells use our UDF so we know which ones
    // to refresh each time the UDF value changes.

    spreadsheet.addCellValueChangeListener(event -> {
        Set<CellReference> cells = event.getChangedCells();

        // A cell has just changed.
        // Lets see if its using our UDF.
        for (CellReference ref : cells)
        {
            Cell cell = spreadsheet.getCell(ref);
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
            {
                // The cell contains a formula so lets see if it contains ours.
                String formula = cell.getCellFormula();
                if (formula.contains(UDFNAME))
                {
                    // Yep it contains our formula
                    // so add it to the tracker.
                    System.out.println("adding" + cell);
                    cellTracker.add(cell);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The cell isn't a formula, but it may have been
                // previously so lets ensure we remove it from tracking.
                System.out.println("Removing cell" + cell);
                if (cellTracker.remove(cell) == true)
                    System.out.println("Removed cell" + cell);
            }
            System.out.println(cellTracker.size());
        }

    });


    /**
     * This is not what you want to do!!
     * 
     * Essentially this is a background thread designed to simulate a price change.
     * In reality you would have a link to some external data source that provided 
     * pricing. Each time the price changes you would update the cells
     * that reference that price.
     * Try to be as selective as possible when choosing the cells to update as 
     * the refresh mechanism is expensive.
     */
    ScheduledExecutorService executor =     Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                UI.getCurrent().access(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                        public void run()
                    {
                        // simulate a stock price change
                        formula.updatePrice();
                        System.out.println("refresh");

                        // refresh all cells that use the stock     price UDF.
                        spreadsheet.refreshCells(cellTracker);
                    }

                });

            }
        }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}


package au.com.noojee.dashboard;

import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.EvaluationException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ValueEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction;

/**
 * 
 * Method to simulate retrieving stock prices
 */
public class GetStockPrice implements FreeRefFunction
{

    // select a random starting price.
    volatile double  currentPrice = 10.50;

    @Override
    public ValueEval evaluate(ValueEval[] args,     OperationEvaluationContext ec)
    {
        double result = 0;

        if (args.length != 2)
        {
            return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
        }

        // The stock code that is being monitored
        String stockCode;
        // The price field that is being pulled (e.g. Bid, Last, High, Low etc)
        String priceField;

        try
        {
            ValueEval v1 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(args[0],     ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex());
            ValueEval v2 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(args[1],     ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex());

            stockCode = OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(v1);
            priceField = OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(v2);

            result = currentPrice;

            checkValue(result);

        }
        catch (EvaluationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getErrorEval();
        }

        return new NumberEval(result);
    }

    /**
     * Excel does not support infinities and NaNs, rather, it gives     a #NUM!
     * error in these cases
     * 
     * @throws EvaluationException
     *             (#NUM!) if <tt>result</tt> is <tt>NaN</> or     <tt>Infinity</tt>
     */
    final void checkValue(double result) throws EvaluationException
    {
        if (Double.isNaN(result) || Double.isInfinite(result))
        {
            throw new EvaluationException(ErrorEval.NUM_ERROR);
        }
    }

    public void updatePrice()
    {
        this.currentPrice += new Random().nextDouble();

    }

}
```